# Better implementation of indexOfPointWithMinimalDistance()

Tags: swift, algorithm, core-graphics

Can this algorithm be improved upon, either in brevity (for example using functional programming) or efficiency?

```
import CoreGraphics 

extension Array where Element == CGPoint {
    
    func indexOfPointWithMinimalDistance(to: CGPoint) -> Int? {
        guard count > 0 else { return nil }
        var minimalDistance : CGFloat!
        var minimalIndex : Int = 0
        for i in 0..<count {
            let d = self[i].distance(to: to)
            if minimalDistance == nil || d < minimalDistance {
                minimalDistance = d
                minimalIndex = i
            }
        }
        return minimalIndex
    }
}

extension CGPoint {
    func distance(to: CGPoint) -> CGFloat { (to-self).length }
    var length : CGFloat { sqrt(x * x + y * y) }
}

func - (left: CGPoint, right: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
    return CGPoint(x: left.x - right.x, y: left.y - right.y)
}
```

Comment: You can use infinity as a starting value to not have to use optional for `minimalDistance`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could avoid calculating the `sqrt( )` because you do not need the value you just want to compare it `<`.

You could also simpify  `minimalDistanceSquare == nil || d < minimalDistanceSquare` by assigning a impossible big value to minimalDistanceSquare during initalization. That would simplify your condition to `d < minimalDistanceSquare`

```
import CoreGraphics 

extension Array where Element == CGPoint {



 func indexOfPointWithMinimalDistance(to: CGPoint) -> Int? {
        guard count > 0 else { return nil }
        var minimalDistanceSquare : CGFloat = CGFloat.infinity
        var minimalIndex : Int = 0
        for i in 0..<count {
            let d = self[i].distanceSquare(to: to)
            if d < minimalDistanceSquare {
                minimalDistanceSquare = d
                minimalIndex = i
            }
        }
        return minimalIndex
    }
}

extension CGPoint {
    func distanceSquare(to: CGPoint) -> CGFloat { (to-self).length }
    var length : CGFloat {x * x + y * y}
}

func - (left: CGPoint, right: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
    return CGPoint(x: left.x - right.x, y: left.y - right.y)
}
```

Comment: Agree with avoiding use of expensive sqrt(), good catch.  Also using infinity first removes unnecessary comparison.  However I'm thinking now we don't need to start i from 0 because we know there is at least one element, so `for i in 1..<count {` and setting `minimalDistanceSquare = self[0].distanceSquare(to: to)` initially.

Comment: Is there a functional programming way of expressing this algorithm in a compact way?  I was thinking that a reduce() could be applicable here, and such an approach could be reused for finding other types of results, ex. max distance

Comment: @andrewz: I agree starting from 1 and initializing with distance of the minimalDistanceSquare = self[0].distanceSquare(to: to) is even better. (Iff we can ensure that there is always at least 1 element.)